# I am trying to limit the amount of tries a user can have but it just outputs indefinitely. Can somebody help me?(Python)

Tags: python

[Code loops the output indefinitely so can somebody assist me here please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aGXu.png)

[image]

Comment: Please post the source code as text

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Remove the inner while loop and move the code inside to the outer while loop. Define `end`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to have the input inside of the outer while loop if you want to be able to stop it.  Currently its outside of both, so it will never modify the value of uchoice.